# Sharepoint online Library can't handle document sets anymore

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document-set

I have a strange issue. I have a document Library on Sharepoint-Online with content types enabaled.
There are some content types of type document and one of type DocumentSet. We have edited a document content type and set some fields on hidden. After that the library can't handle DocumentSets anymore.

Behavior:

- Existing DocumentSets are still visibile and can be accessed via DocSet-Homepage.
  but when I click on "Edit Properties" I only see on single field to be edit (should be 29 fileds)
- When I try to create a new DocSet I do see all fields just like expected but it shows "New Folder" and there is no save button
- The same issue with create new DocSet is also present when I add a new content type of type "DocumentSet". It always shows "New Folder" on the NewScreen
- When I create a new Library and add DocumentSets it works just like expected

Any Ideas what the issue could be and how to solve it?

Comment: Are you using the modern experience for this document library?

Comment: No. We use classic experience